# imagemagick: append a label under image with font size

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

How to append a label under an image with a font size?

```
convert image.png -label "Test label" -pointsize 100 -gravity center -append image.png
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
convert image.png -pointsize 36 label:"Test label" -gravity center -append result.png
```

[image]

When you use `xc:`, `label:`, `pattern:` and `gradient:` (i.e. all the ones with no dash at the start and a colon at the end), ImageMagick creates a canvas for you to put the data on.

Comment: Strange. Although I use -gravity center the text stays on the left side.

Comment: @Juergen is `-gravity center` *before* `-append`?  Arguments to ImageMagick are case sensitive.