# imagemagick: append label, gravity buggy

Tags: imagemagick

I was trying to reproduce the hint in

[imagemagick: append a label under image with font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942892/imagemagick-append-a-label-under-image-with-font-size)

This is my source image:

[image]

```
convert red.png -pointsize 36 label:"Test label" -gravity center -append red2.png
```

But instead of the expected result (label placed on bottom centered) I got this

[image]

I don't think that imagemagick has a bug. So, what am I doing wrong?

Here the version's info

```
convert -version
```

> GraphicsMagick 1.4 snapshot-20181020 Q16
>   http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/ Copyright (C) 2002-2018 GraphicsMagick
>   Group. Additional copyrights and licenses apply to this software. See
>   http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/www/Copyright.html for details.
>
> Feature Support:   Native Thread Safe       yes   Large Files (> 32
>   bit)   yes   Large Memory (> 32 bit)  yes   BZIP
>   yes   DPS                      no   FlashPix                 no
>   FreeType                 yes   Ghostscript (Library)    no   JBIG
>   yes   JPEG-2000                no   JPEG                     yes
>   Little CMS               yes   Loadable Modules         no   OpenMP
>   yes (201511)   PNG                      yes   TIFF
>   yes   TRIO                     no   UMEM                     no   WebP
>   yes   WMF                      yes   X11                      yes
>   XML                      yes   ZLIB                     yes
>
> Host type: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
>
> Configured using the command:   ./configure  '--build'
>   'x86_64-linux-gnu' '--enable-shared' '--enable-static'
>   '--enable-libtool-verbose' '--prefix=/usr'
>   '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info'
>   '--docdir=${prefix}/share/doc/graphicsmagick'
>   '--with-gs-font-dir=/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts' '--with-x'
>   '--x-includes=/usr/include/X11' '--x-libraries=/usr/lib/X11'
>   '--without-dps' '--without-modules' '--without-frozenpaths'
>   '--with-webp' '--with-perl' '--with-perl-options=INSTALLDIRS=vendor'
>   '--enable-quantum-library-names' '--with-quantum-depth=16'
>   'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2
>   -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/graphicsmagick-1.3.30+hg15796=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time
>   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/graphicsmagick-1.3.30+hg15796=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security'
>
> Final Build Parameters:   CC       = gcc   CFLAGS   = -fopenmp -g -O2
>   -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/graphicsmagick-1.3.30+hg15796=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -pthread   CPPFLAGS = -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -I/usr/include/X11 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libxml2   CXX      = g++   CXXFLAGS = -g -O2
>   -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/graphicsmagick-1.3.30+hg15796=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -pthread   LDFLAGS  = -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -L/usr/lib/X11
>   -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu   LIBS     = -ljbig -lwebp -lwebpmux -llcms2 -ltiff -lfreetype -ljpeg -lpng16 -lwmflite -lXext -lSM -lICE -lX11 -llzma -lbz2 -lxml2 -lz -lm -lgomp -lpthread

Comment: Judging by the  version info, you are using GraphicsMagick so I don't understand why you call it ImageMagick and tag it as such when it isn't. ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick are two different things.

Comment: That's a point. I was not aware of this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Mark I was able to spot the error.

It looks like I had GraphicsMagick and ImageMagick installed in parallel and somehow they both seam to interfere each other. I really have no clue.

So I uninstalled GraphicsMagick with all dependencies (which I never used) and reinstalled ImageMagick.

Now it works as it should.

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick, label: creates a new image. So you need to append that below your red image. To do that you should use parenthesis processing to create the label: image. It is cleaner to read that way.

```
convert red.png \( -background white -fill black -pointsize 36 label:"Test label" \) -gravity center -append red2.png
```

[image]

See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#label